# php doubts. what happens if two people access the same script at the same time?

Tags: php, user-input, execution-time

i've made a php search engine a while ago and now i have this doubt that i already searched for it and saw a lot of questions here on stack overflow talking about multiple simultaneous accesses to php scripts but only regarding appending, modifying etc...

let's say my search engine (or any other script that based on user input generates different responses) would take 20 seconds to end searching.

user A accesses the script

user B accesses the script 10 seconds later than user A (so the script didn't 'answered' user A yet)

what will happen? will the server "execute another instance of the file" and so both users will have their responses or will something be messed up?

also if a php script takes a long time to finish execution and a person accesses it and then leaves without waiting for the response, will the php script still do everything it has to do until it reaches the end? (logic tells me that on this last question the script will do everything until it reaches the end because the person just makes the request, then waits for the answer to come and if it closes still nothing is going to stop the php script from executing, but i'm still asking because i want to be completely sure)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both persons have their own instance of your script. There could still be problems concerning data consistency if data is modified. With HTTP being a stateless protocol, you don't know if a person leaves without waiting for the result, the script will run to the end.

Comment: i figured that if data was modified bad stuff would happen but i was concerned that bad stuff would happen even if no data was modified, but fortunately it doesn't, thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

every user's session processes with a Threads. every thing is in queue and nothing messes up.

but in some conditions problems may occur.

ex: a user asks for a certain field in DB but another user deletes that field while 1st user's thread is waiting or suspended. but it is really rear and if it happens an exception will be throne and it's our scripts duty to handle it.